# SSRS Chart: Y-Axis Minimum Expression

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I've got a few bar charts that shows 2 budget sets and an "actuals" for the year.  Generally, I allow SSRS to automatically scale the charts, but we have 1 chart with a 1 month anomaly, where we had to budget a negative.  This is unlikely to happen again, but I'd prefer to write an expression, rather than hard code a minimum.

SSRS is assigning the Y-Axis to -500, but the value is only -117, so I'd prefer to have the minimum be something along the lines of (MINIMUM Value * 1.2).

I found this question, [SSRS Line Chart Dynamic Y Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128069/ssrs-line-chart-dynamic-y-axis), and tried to adapt it to my needs, but failed.
 I tried the following expression in the Y-Axis Minimum:
`=iif(MIN(Sum(Fields!ForecastAmt.Value,"Chart3_CategoryGroup2"))<0,(MIN(Sum(Fields!ForecastAmt.Value,"Chart3_CategoryGroup2"))*1.2),Nothing)`

Comment: It looks like it should work - I've done similar things in the past. Are you getting an error? Any warnings? What is the Axis' min value?

Comment: Sorry for responding late, had a long weekend.  I'm not receiving any error or warnings.  The lowest value on the chart is -117.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I wanted the chart to handle the range and a rogue value was messing with the chart rendering.

[image: Value of zero drops the y-axis min range to -20]

My requirement is: if there is a value <= zero, set the min axis range to zero, else let the chart handle it and here is the expression

```
 =IIF(Min(Fields!MyField.Value, "MyDataSource") <= 0 OR Min(Fields!MyField.Value, "MyDataSource") <= 0, 0, "Auto")
```

Your expression looks mostly ok, perhaps remove the SUM()?